# Solving Gaps and Islands in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, gaps-and-islands

We are replacing an old system with SSAS in SQL Server 2016. An existing report that needs to be replaced in the new system looks like this:

```
From Date   To Date     Days   Cash      Settled    Rate (%)    Interest
2017-01-01  2017-01-03   3     1000.00   1500.00    3.13        0.39
2017-01-04  2017-01-04   1     1100.00   1500.00    3.13        0.13
2017-01-05  2017-01-05   1     1100.00   1600.00    3.33        0.15
```

The underlying data would be this:

```
Date        Cash      Settled    Rate (%)    Interest
2017-01-01  1000.00   1500.00    3.13        0.13
2017-01-02  1000.00   1500.00    3.13        0.13
2017-01-03  1000.00   1500.00    3.13        0.13
2017-01-04  1100.00   1500.00    3.13        0.13
2017-01-05  1100.00   1600.00    3.33        0.15
```

The report basically groups all rows where Cash, Settled, and Rate are the same. I found a similar issue in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167068/solving-gaps-and-islands-with-row-number-and-dense-rank) but it is for SQL. Right now I use that for the report but would like to use MDX for better aggregation since the daily values consist of many detail rows.

In a twist to the above it is also possible that Settled, Rate, or all three (plus the derived Interest) are NULL.

I believe this issue is referred to as the Gaps and Islands problem. Has anyone any ideas on how to solve it in MDX?

Comment: In sake of performance you will need to calculate it on DWH anyway. Are you sure you need a pure MDX solution calculated on the SSAS side?

Comment: I agree with Danylo - this is going to be tricky via pure mdx - my initial observation is that most cubes only have a single date dimension so your requirement of columns for  `From Date` and `To Date` becomes tricky

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I already have a solution in SQL but my managers keep bugging me about doing aggregations in the cube. Since I could not find anyone talking about this problem outside of SQL I assumed it would be tricky. I will probably keep the current solution then.